# Change the numbering of figures in latex to per chapter and per section

Tags: floats, numbering

I want to change the numbering of my figures in my latex file from ordinal (1,2,...) to chapter.section.number (1.1.1, 1.1.2 ,...). I used the **chngcntr** package and the

`\counterwithin{figure}{chapter} \counterwithin{figure}{section}`

commands before my first chapter, but the numbering of all figures changes to 0.0.(number of figure). I suppose this means that the package cannot identify the beginning of each chapter and section. The document type is `\documentclass[oneside]{um}`. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to fix that issue? Since I am new to using LaTeX I would appreciate it if the answers were a little simplified. Thank you in advance.

````
\documentclass[oneside]{um}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Theory and Methods}

\section{random name 1}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{Example of a Decision Tree structure}
    \label{Figure:1}
\end{figure}

\chapter{number 2}

\section{random name 2}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image}
    \caption{example 2}
    \label{Figure:1}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}```
````

Comment: `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` should be enough. The section number also changes when the chapter changes, so there's no need for the command with "chapter" as well.  I doubt you need the chngctr package. But if the problem persists, please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that); if the problem is only reproducible with the `um` document class, we'll need a link to it, since it's not on CTAN as far as I know.

Comment: I assume that somewhere you have `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}` and `\renewcommand{\thesection|{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}`

Comment: No I don't John Kormylo. Is it necessary and if so where should i use it.

Comment: @frabjous, I tried using just the ```\counterwithin{figure}{section}``` but the same problems persists.

Comment: I created this project using the same template and everything else like my project. I just emptied it out and left 2 figures so you can experiment on. https://www.overleaf.com/5229335416zjsrhmdzwfzy

Comment: Post your example here. I don't have an Overleaf account, and don't want one. Moreover, this site should be self-contained.

Comment: @frabjous I don't know how to post the example here, because it is very big. If you can't  check it via the link I posted it's ok. Thank you for trying.

Comment: It shouldn't be very big. Half the point of a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) is to be minimal. Keep working on reducing it until you have a MWE, then edit the question and post it there. If it's still too big, use a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and post the link here, but it shouldn't be that big if you follow the instructions in the MWE link.

Comment: @frabjous I am using a custom template so there are many things in the environment and I can't post them all here. I posted a basic similar example, but I don't know if that is enough.

Comment: A minimal working example needs to be a complete document; yours is missing a document class. It also needs to demonstrate the problem. If I add `\documentclass{report}` or `\documentclass{book}`, the figures are numbered correctly. You can remove each thing from the template line by line, and only restore those things necessary to recreate the issue. If you want help, you need to take the steps to make it possible for others to help you. I've already suggested a pastebin. Is um.cls [this here](https://github.com/jp-um/university_of_malta_LaTeX_dissertation_template/)?

Comment: The project is of class \documentclass[oneside]{um}. It has a custom template for my dissertation, so there are many hidden files it uses. Is there a chance that the um document class prevent the numbering form being this way?